# Is there a way to add Firebase custom claims with stripe one-time payments?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am trying to add a custom claim with firebase after a one time payment with stripe. For subscriptions, the metadata in stripe works to put the custom claim on the auth object, but for one time payments this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

I tried setting the metadata value on the one-time payment in stripe, but it did not add the custom claim to the auth object.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a listener for the price collection and changing the custom claims in the cloud function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).